# Flask_Mongoengine: Not a mongoengine object after using aggregate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

When use `aggregate` with mongoengine, it return a CommandCursor instead of mongoengine object list, which mean that the mongonengine is not really be used,

For example: if some document doesn't has a title field, a error will be raised. How can I convert my results to mongoengine object?

```
class Post(Document):
    title = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
    author = ReferenceField(User)

Host.objects()
# [<Post: Post object>, <Post: Post object>, ...]

pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            'types': type,
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            'brating': {
                "$divide": [
                    {"$add": ["$total_score", 60]},
                    {"$add": ["$total_votes", 20]}
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {"$sort": {"brating": -1}},
    {"$limit": 100}

]

Host.objects.aggregate(*pipeline)
# <class 'pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor'>

list(Host.objects.aggregate(*pipeline))
# <class 'list'>
```

Comment: It may be worth posting a new question which explains why you need to use aggregate at all here. Usually an aggregation pipeline is used to transform and combine multiple document rather than just retrieve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aggregate` function is just a shortcut to the underlying [pymongo function](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate).

The documents that come back from `aggregate` may involve some `$group` or other stage that means they bear no relation to your object model so mongoengine couldn't convert them to mongoengine objects.

In the case of your pipeline you are using a `$project` stage to return a new type of document which only has `name` and `brating` fields.

Mongoengine isn't going to be able to do what you want here so you have a couple options:

- Store the `brating` field on the `Post` documents. Initialise the rating at 0 when the post is created and when `$total_score` or `$total_votes` are updated, also update the rating.
- Accept that you are getting back non-mongoengine objects and handle them accordingly. The cursor will yield normal python dictionaries which you can then access the fields `post['name']` or `post['brating']` in your client code.
- Use a normal `.objects` query and sort on the client side.

The final step will obliviously be a problem if you have lots of documents but for a small number try something like:

```
posts = Post.objects(types=type).only("name", "total_score", "total_votes")
top_posts = sorted(list(posts),key=lambda p: (p.total_score+60)/(p.total_votes+20))[:100]
```

Comment: The problem is I have to use `aggregate` for some complex query mongoengine can't handle it, is there no way to use them same time？

Comment: Why can't mongoengine handle the query? Maybe post your pipeline in the question.

Comment: I just added pipeline code, please give it a look and how I can do it with mongoengine's `.objects` notation.

Comment: It's hard to answer because you haven't given a [complete question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but I've added some options. You are not going to be able to do what you want with mongoengine, although it is technically possible to implement what you are requesting you would have to write it yourself so it may be easier to look at other ways of doing this.

Comment: Thanks. The solution of example code is working on my case, what I still can't sure is which method has better performance? use mongoengine objects then iterate it, calculate new field, sorted it, or use aggregate of pymongo then check each field in flask template manually. BTW: my collection has about 4000 documents.

Comment: If you are worried about performance then pymongo will always be quickest. You will just need to adjust your template code as you suggest.